Running a Python script in Robot Framework and waiting for it to complete
In my Robot Framework test, I am running a Python script that creates test data.
To start the script there are 2 options:
in PowerShell I can type:
python testdatascript.py ABC TEST
or
python testdatascript.py -> the script runs and ask for input -> ABC -> next input TEST
Where "ABC" = sourceDB, and "TEST" = environment
I think current code I have is not 'waiting' to finish the generation, as when I manually run it in PowerShell it can take 20secs - 1min for all test data to be generated before completing the script. While in Robot Framework it finishes in 1-2 seconds (without making the files with testdata)
The Python script is working fine and works flawless when using manually.
Currently I have this:
${RESULT}= Run Process   Python   c:/path/testdatascript.py   ABC TEST   shell=yes   stdout=stdout.txt 

it currently gives back <result object with rc 0> (which is 0 errors if I am correct) But does not create the testdata.
If the script runs successfully, it will print: successfully created the testdata If it fails it will print  an error code.
I started looking into Start Process , but I'm not experienced enough in Robot framework to know how that would work.
Perfect solution would be if the Run/Start Process kicks of the .py script and checks if the Successfull line is shown before continuing the test.

Run Process keyword returns a Result Object which is documented here; https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object
On this object, it has attribute called rc which is return code of the process you ran. The output of your process can be read from attributes stdout and stderr. Do read the docs, in certain scenarios you might need to redirect the output's to a file to avoid hangups. And looking at your example, you are already passing the stdout to Run Process, so the output could be read it from a file pointed out in stdout_path attribute.
If the script does not work as intended when its executed from robot framework but it still returns 0 as exit code, i'd assume that the script itself has some issues.
